# Creating mixed multi axis charts in chartjs

Tags: chart.js

I am trying a chart which has two-axis (which is achieved http://www.futuresnoptions.com/amol/index.html). But now I want a mixed chart with multiple axes something like this http://techanjs.org/.

I want to show the stock chart line (on one axis) vs Open-interest (another axis).

In the bottom show bar chart which is the difference between Open-Interest and Mean of Open-Interest. The positive bars are shown in green and negative charts in red. Somehow this mixed with multiple axes is what I am not able to work upon and also there is no readymade example to help...

Note: I am open to any javascript opensource library if it is possible

Comment: "there is no readymade example to help" The Chart.js [website](https://www.chartjs.org/) provides [dozens of examples](https://www.chartjs.org/samples) to help you get started. There's [one for multi-axis charts](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/multi-axis.html) and [one for mixed type charts](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/combo-bar-line.html).

Comment: Thank you ... I will check it out and try building one